# HOW to create a .bat file that will ping 7 random hosts?

Tags: batch-file, ip, ping, host

I'm trying to make a .bat file that pings arbitrary hosts, but my options are not working. Maybe someone can help with this question

Answer (score 0):

Why not scan all devices at once? You can do it in seconds

Create a file named `Scan.bat`

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)
arp -d
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /i "192"`) do (
for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
set _o1=%%c
set _o2=%%d
set _o3=%%e
set _o4=%%f
set _3octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.
for /L %%a in (1,1,254) do (start /min ping /n 1 /l 1 !_3octet!%%a)
)))
endlocal
```

Run the above file every time before typing the command below

```
arp -a | findstr 192 | findstr dynamic
```

You can then view all the devices connected to your network with this command